# How does sql evaluate ISNUMERIC(ISNULL(VALUE, 'blah'))

Tags: t-sql

My assumption was that it would return a true if that value was numeric (within the isnumeric range) but `FALSE` if the `ISNULL` returns `'blah'`. Seems like my assumption was off...

I'm using the it in the following way

```
case when ISNULL(ISNUMERIC(c.npinumber), 'blah') = 1
       then c.NPiNUmber
     else 'not valid: ' + c.NpiNumber
     end as npi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building on Dhruvesh's answer,

```
case
    when ISNUMERIC(c.npinumber) = 1 then c.NPiNUmber
    else 'not valid: ' + c.NpiNumber
end as npi
```

Will produce NULL anytime NpiNumber is NULL.  The reason is that NULL + any string will still return NULL.  The solution is to simply use the COALESCE function

```
case
    when ISNUMERIC(c.npinumber) = 1 then c.NPiNUmber
    else 'not valid: ' + COALESCE(c.NpiNumber, 'NULL VALUE')
end as npi
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select  ISNUMERIC(ISNULL(NULL, 'blah')),
        ISNUMERIC(ISNULL(1234, 'blah')),
        ISNUMERIC(ISNULL('ab', 'blah'))
```

Returns 0, 1, 0 - so your logic is correct.

When SQL's not behaving I like to simplify my query. Try running the query without your case statement first. If the results look right, then add additional logic.

What collation is your database? It's always a good idea to keep your column names properly cased (I'm looking at that all-lowercase column name over there...).

Comment: Euric, sorry, my fault on the insertion of the differed logic. I tried it both ways with the same result.

Comment: I edited my original response. I don't think the ISNULL call is adding anything to your statement. A call to ISNUMERIC only will have the same effect.

Comment: When used in the CASE statement the logic fails to invoke the ELSE.

Answer (score 2):

You don't require ISNULL. ISNUMERIC will return 1 if it's numberic or 0 if it's NULL or  non-numeric.

```
  case
       when ISNUMERIC(c.NpiNumber) = 1 then c.NPiNUmber
       else 'not valid: ' + c.NpiNumber
  end as npi
```

Also as Euric Mentioned you may want to look at your all-lowercase column name.

Comment: Actually the ISNUMERIC(ISNULL(value, 'blah')) Returns 0, 1, 0, exactly as logic predicts. However when the logic in the case statement returns a 0 (when value is NULL) it should invoke the else 'not valid: '. It does not, it still returns a NULL value.

Sorry about the lowercase uppercase, was just typing fast, not looking at pretty, just trying to understand the non-logic ;-)